# HP Trim web service- how to request a record.?

Tags: trim

I am dealing with HP Trim web service with no support at all. I have to set a request of file using web service. i think i have to set following properties but i am not sure what operation this will be added in.

```
rcqCurrentLoc(Current Location): 
rcqDetails(Details): 
rcqEndDate(Date of Final Request): 
rcqFrequency(Frequency): 
rcqFrequencyType(Frequency Type): 
rcqHomeLoc(Home Location): 
rcqNotes(Notes): 
rcqRecord(Object): 
rcqRequestDate(Date Object Needed): 
rcqRequestor(Requested By):
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at wrong properties. The request properties are following

```
uri(Unique Identifier): 
reqEndDate(Date of Final Request): 
reqFrequency(Frequency): 
reqFrequencyType(Frequency Type): 
reqName(Request Info): 
reqNotes(Notes): 
reqRequestDate(Date Needed): 
reqRequestor(Requested By):
```

and the code is

```
public void AddFileRequest(string FileUri,string RequestorUserId, DateTime DateNeeded)
        {


List<InputProperty> properties = new List<InputProperty>();

        InputProperty property = new InputProperty();
        property.Name = ReqRequstor;
        property.Val = GetUserUri(RequestorUserId);
        properties.Add(property);

        property = new InputProperty();
        property.Name = ReqRequestDate;
        property.Val = DateNeeded.ToString();
        properties.Add(property);

        ShortcutRecordUri uri = new ShortcutRecordUri();
        uri.Uri = FileUri;
        uri.IsForUpdate = true;

        CreateChildItem create = new CreateChildItem();
        create.ChildObjectType = ObjectTypeRequest;
        create.Items = properties.ToArray();

        TrimRequest request = new TrimRequest();
        request.Items = new Operation[] { uri, create };

        ExecuteRequest(request);
    }
```